# Python Discord trying to get the bot to exit after the song has finished playing

Tags: python, while-loop, discord, discord.py

I am trying to get the bot to exit after the song has finished playing.
I've made several attempts, but the bot doesn't leave the channel after not playing a song, can someone help me?

```
    while ctx.voice_client.is_connected():
        if ctx.voice.client.is_playing():
            time.sleep(30)
        else:
            time.sleep(60)
            embed = discord.Embed(
            title=f'Leave',
            description=f'I left the Voice Channel.',
            color=0xFF5733
        )
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
            await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()
```

Comment: "Can someone help me" it's too vague, please give us more details, take a look at [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score -2):

You should use `asyncio.sleep`.

```
import asyncio
await asyncio.sleep(10)
```